# ImmutableList.builder() bug?

Tags: java, guava

I'm just starting out to learn Guava and I notice something peculiar with `ImmutableList.builder()`.

This doesn't compile:

```
List<String> iList = ImmutableList.builder().add("One").add("Two").build(); 
//Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>
```

This works:

```
List<String> iList = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>().add("One").add("Two").build();
```

I can live with using `new ImmutableList.Builder<String>()` but is this a bug with `ImmutableList.builder()`?

Comment: Java 8 has made some strong improvements in type inference, I don't know if this specific case is better addressed, but I'd suspect it is.

Comment: @dimo414 I compiled this in Java 8 and 7. It doesn't work in either one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, just provide a type argument

```
List<String> iList = ImmutableList.<String>builder().add("One").add("Two").build();
```

This is in no way a bug in Guava, it is just a feature/limitation of the Java Language. The compiler cannot infer the return type of `build()` from the previous method calls or the declaration of the variable the result is being assigned to.

Angelika Langer [explains](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20argument%20inference?) this

> **Automatic type argument inference.** The method is invoked like regular
> non-generic methods, that is, without specification of the type
> arguments.  In this case the compiler automatically infers the type
> arguments from **the invocation context**.

She also gives a similar example in [Why does the type inference for an instance creation expression fail?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Why%20does%20the%20type%20inference%20for%20an%20instance%20creation%20expression%20fail?)

```
String s = new ArrayList<>().iterator().next();  // error
```

and states

> In the example above an error message is issued because the new-expression `new ArrayList<>()` does not have constructor arguments and it neither appears on the right-hand side of an assignment nor as
> the argument of a method invocation.  Instead, it appears in a chain
> of method calls.  Such a chain is not a valid type inference context.